# How do I populate a column with a deleted timestamp column for whenever a row is soft-deleted?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table and a deleteddatetime column that I want to populate with a timestamp when another column, logically_deleted is changed from '0' to '1.'

How do I do this on a row level? Would I use a trigger? And if so how if I can't do a row level trigger in SQL Server?

Comment: With a trigger. You can do row-level triggers in SQL Server, but in this case you don't need them. All rows were updated at the same time, so all will get the same timestamp

Comment: Before you proceed with this you should consider that soft deletes are a terrible idea and *definitely* not what business users really asked for. With soft deletes you lose the ability to use contstraints and foreign keys. If you "soft delete" a record, what happens to other records that reference it? Check Oren Eini's [Avoid Soft Deletes](https://ayende.com/blog/4157/avoid-soft-deletes). In SQL Server 2016 and later, you can replace soft deletes with temporal tables

Comment: For this use-case, we want to keep those records in the table even if not pulling them. Also, my issue is that I don't want to get the same timestamp. I want the deleteddatetime to be null if the row hasn't been deleted.

Comment: hat's not a use case, that's an implementation, with known problems. What you ask is  what a normal trigger will do anyway. Add a check to only update the timestamp if the `isDeleted` column is modified.

Comment: I'm still learning how to create triggers (as is probably pretty evident lol), so what would the basic syntax for that look like? particularly what would adding a check to only update on the timestamp w/ the modified isdeleted column look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger will have to look like this:

```
create trigger [yourtriggernamehere] on [yourtablename]
for 
update as
if update(logically_deleted)

begin

    update [yourtablename] set deleteddatetime = getdate() where inserted.[idcolumnoftable] = [idcolumnoftable]

end
```

Remember to populate the fields with [] then this trigger should work.

It might need a few tweaks, but this is generally what it would look like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks so much! with a bit of tweaking it worked perfectly

Comment: That's great to hear, please remember to mark the answer as your answer... @MARIANNEDOLAN :-)